# Using spTransform CRS in Leaflet

Tags: coordinate-system, r, leaflet, sp

I am producing Kernel density estimates for animals from tracking data.

Location is input at `x` `y` data, I produce a spatial polygons dataframe from these coordinates.

```
xy<-id[c("X", "Y")]
id<-id[c("Individual")]
idsp <- data.frame(id)
coordinates(idsp) <- xy
proj4string(idsp)
```

I set the CRS

```
proj4string(idsp) <- CRS("+proj=utm +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
```

I then use adehabitatHR to produce KDE95s for my individual animals using the kernelUD and getverticeshr.

```
cromKDE<- kernelUD(idsp, h = "href")
CromKDE95 <- getverticeshr(cromKDE, percent = 95)
```

I convert these outputs into the appropriate CRS for the package leaflet using

```
CromKDE95<- spTransform(CromKDE95, CRS('+init=epsg:4326'))
```

I then try to use the package leaflet to visualise the KDE95 polygons on a basemap

```
leaflet(CromKDE95) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons().
```

But the polygons are plotting in the Ocean south of San-Pedro rather than in Ireland as they should be.

I realise this is likely a simple fix adjusting the CRS but I have tried all the different formats I can think of.

Comment: Where are you getting `CRS("+proj=utm +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")` - that's an uncommon reference system and I'm wondering if someone has said "this is UTM" when in fact its in a UTM *zone* - which means you need the zone number...

Answer (score 0):

```
CromKDE95 <-sp::CRS("+init=epsg:29902")
```

Try this using the EPSG format for ireland (29902)